# login view using NSURLSession post request

Tags: objective-c, authentication, http-post, redmine, nsurlsession

I am trying to have a login view for an ios app,
this is the page I am trying to access http://demo.redmine.org/login
I tried to use NSURLConnection but it is not available with ios 9.
Let me know If there is something wrong with my code here.

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    NSString *username = @"admin";
    NSString *password = @"admin";
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",username, password];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu" , (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.16.231.19/redmine23/login"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/JSON" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                      if (error) {
                                          // Handle error...
                                          return;
                                      }

                                      if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                          NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                                          NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                                      }

                                      NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);
                                  }];
    [task resume];
```

This is what I got :

```
    2016-02-09 04:49:19.336 testLoginApp[9574:1247112] Response HTTP Headers:
{
    "Content-Length" = 1208;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 09 Feb 2016 09:48:44 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    "X-Request-Id" = c24707e081ab5a8fbd5d3e0ff701b854;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.126006";
}
2016-02-09 04:49:23.312 testLoginApp[9574:1247112] Response Body:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: r u able to login through browser with the same url ? Try to use postman google chrome plugin, and see if you can do the post session.

Comment: I looked inside and found out that there is "POST" method for login. I found that the "Content-Type" = "text/html"; so what do you think?

Comment: Try adding "Accept" : "application/json" to your headers.

Comment: I don't think it support "application/json", it only accept  (text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8)

Comment: I got it to work by changing the "Content-Type" = "text/html" this is the Response HTTP Status code: 200 -- I tried to create a UI webview, and added the webview as subview to check that the login was success, unfortunately the login was not successful it's said Invalid user or password  even thou the username and password were correct. I don't know know what's wrong now. How to pass the username and password :/

Comment: I figured that out by using the postman, it worked!!! Thank you all for the help I will post my answer now : ) thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

That's the full code for the login view,
I changed the string of the username and password username=%@&password=%@, I also changed the value for Content-Type, as Mr.T suggest to use postman to test the post session and get the code of the request.

```
NSString *username = @"admin";
NSString *password = @"admin";
got the format from postman by having a key and a value for the username and password
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",username, password];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu" , (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demo.redmine.org/login"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 got the value for the Content-Type from postman
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];



        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request

                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                          if (error) {
                                              // Handle error...
                                              return;
                                          }

                                          if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                              NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                                              NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                                          }

                                          NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                          NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);
                                      }];
        [task resume];
        UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
```